# What source is this citation referencing?

Tags: citations

I want to find the source of a footnote in a book (footnote 18), but I don't understand the way sources are cited.

I want to find source #18. Here is the **Notes** page:

```
...
...
...
17. AT, VI.18-19.
18. Ibid., p.20
...
...
...
```

I found out on Wikipedia that *Ibid* in #18 is referencing the source above (I think), but what does `AT, VI.18-19.` mean?

This might seem like a stupid question, but I really don't understand how this works, and I don't know how to find out--other than asking here. I've tried searching on google, but I don't even know what to search for.

If you need more info from the book let me know.

EDIT:

Here is the book:

https://books.google.com/books?id=_quBG-_aqJsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=18&f=false

Page 267

Comment: I'd suggest you look in the bibliography. The notes give shorthand references to works in the bibliography.

Comment: A.T. is probably the abbreviation for a work's title or author -- see if anything matches that.

Comment: This may fit better on Academic.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Off topic - this seems to fit in more with Academic.SE or Literature.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is page 285, which says:

> Adam, Charles and Tannery, Paul (eds), Oeuvres de Descartes, 2nd edn (Paris: Vrin, 1974-86). (This is abbreviated AT in 
>   the endnotes.)